# How can I ensure that a network call is not executed on the main thread using a handler?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networkonmainthread

I am getting an exception (android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException) when using
`Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); handler.post(runnable);`. The runnable includes a network call (closing a socket). What is the difference between handler and an async handler? not sure if that could be handy here.

Comment: You have to create a new thread with its own looper to run any code on a separate thread.

Comment: Check out the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Comment: Using a `Handler` to move logic onto a background thread is an extremely low-level solution. You might want to consider [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/115145).